# Recaptcha Solver Audio selection issue

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory, recaptcha

I have this captcha solving script, it always worked perfectly until yesterday:

```
def solve_captcha(driver):
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")))
  frames = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")

  recaptcha_control_frame = None
  recaptcha_challenge_frame = None
  for index, frame in enumerate(frames):
      if re.search('reCAPTCHA', frame.get_attribute("title")):
          recaptcha_control_frame = frame

      if re.search('recaptcha challenge', frame.get_attribute("title")):
          recaptcha_challenge_frame = frame

  #click recaptcha
  driver.switch_to.frame(recaptcha_control_frame)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "recaptcha-checkbox-border")))
  driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "recaptcha-checkbox-border").click()
  driver.switch_to.default_content()

  #click on audio challenge
  driver.switch_to.frame(recaptcha_challenge_frame)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "recaptcha-audio-button")))
  driver.find_element(By.ID, "recaptcha-audio-button").click()
  driver.switch_to.default_content()

  #switch to recaptcha audio challenge frame
  driver.switch_to.frame(recaptcha_challenge_frame)

  path_to_wav = find_and_export_wav()
  solution = solve(path_to_wav)
  result = submit_and_check(solution, recaptcha_control_frame)
  return result
```

When I was debugging I found out that the error is generated when this line of code executed:
`WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "recaptcha-audio-button")))`

And I get this error:

```
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55cdd7ef77f9 <unknown>
#1 0x55cdd7e973b3 <unknown>
#2 0x55cdd7bdf016 <unknown>
#3 0x55cdd7c1381e <unknown>
#4 0x55cdd7c498fb <unknown>
#5 0x55cdd7c36ded <unknown>
#6 0x55cdd7c479e1 <unknown>
#7 0x55cdd7c36c93 <unknown>
#8 0x55cdd7c08ce4 <unknown>
#9 0x55cdd7c0a4d2 <unknown>
#10 0x55cdd7ec3542 <unknown>
#11 0x55cdd7ed2ce7 <unknown>
#12 0x55cdd7ed29e4 <unknown>
#13 0x55cdd7ed713a <unknown>
#14 0x55cdd7ed35b9 <unknown>
#15 0x55cdd7eb8e00 <unknown>
#16 0x55cdd7eea5d2 <unknown>
#17 0x55cdd7eea778 <unknown>
#18 0x55cdd7f02a1f <unknown>
#19 0x7f93e9c40b43 <unknown>
#20 0x7f93e9cd2a00 <unknown>
```

What could be the reason?

I tried changing the search with class name instead of id and same issue.

Comment: What is your selenium version?

Comment: I remember when I was working with selenium 3, `WebDriverWait` was buggy. So, I implemented it myself.

Comment: Can you give a url where this captcha comes up?

Comment: @JesseSealand google recaptcha demo is the same

Answer (score 3):

It looks like reCaptcha has changed its website structure. Try Inspecting the page.

Comment: Best answer for such undetailed question.